# Get Month number in calculated column using column engine

Tags: hana, hana-studio

I have the following fields:

```
Subscription = Semi Annual, Quarterly, Monthly. 
Start Date = (Jun 1,2023, Jun 10,223)
```

I want to build a calculated column using `IF statement (column engine)` and month function (SQL)
such as:

```
IF("Subscription"='Semi Annual' AND month("start Date")<=6,month("start date")+6,
0)
```

Is there a function in column engine which will get the month number of the start date.

Currently, I have created a separate calculated column using:

```
Language = SQL
First month = month(start date)
```

and I am using this calculated column in my other calculated columns.

As there are a bunch of calculated columns that are referencing `"First month"` I would like to collapse all in.